# esp8266 без ардуины

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, esp8266

Где найти информацию о том как писать софт для esp8266 или esp32 без платформы ардуино, на чистом С? Да и в целом под микроконтроллеры, какие нибудь примеры допустим с подключением к WiFi, и io на пины.

Только начинаю в этом всем разбираться и ардуино уже выглядит как оверхед и игрушка, нежели что то серьезное.

Comment: Без платы Arduino или без Arduino IDE?

Comment: без платы, что бы вообще не использовалась никакая технология или фича с корнями arduino.

Comment: Можно писать в Arduino IDE, из нее же прошивать ESP. При этом работать будет без платы Arduino. Вот тут самое основное описано: [ESP-8266 - Wi-Fi модуль как самостоятельный контроллер](http://wiki.amperka.ru/продукты:esp8266-wifi-module#wi-fi_модуль_как_самостоятельный_контроллер) (там рассматривается использование "голого" модуля без USB, но есть платы с USB, на них процесс прошивки упрощается). В целом программирование такого модуля не сильно отличается от программирования платы Arduino. Есть способы программирования модуля без использования Arduino IDE, но это намного сложнее.